# What is the difference between ip nhrp nhs and ip nhrp map?

Tags: tunnel, gre

These two commands seems similar when I configure a DMVPN Spoke. What is the difference?

```
interface Tunnel1
 ip address 192.168.88.2 255.255.255.248
 no ip redirects
 **ip nhrp map 192.168.88.1 10.0.1.1**
 ip nhrp map multicast 10.0.1.1
 ip nhrp network-id 1
 **ip nhrp nhs 192.168.88.1**
 tunnel source FastEthernet0/0
 tunnel mode gre multipoint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [PacketLife.net](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/jul/23/dynamic-multipoint-vpn-dmvpn/):

Assuming router **foo** is configured as the Next-Hop Server, has a physical interface with IP address 10.0.1.1, and a tunnel interface with IP address 192.168.88.1 whose source is the 10.0.1.1 interface, then

*ip nhrp nhs 192.168.88.1* designates router **foo** as the Next-Hop Server.

*ip nhrp map 192.168.88.1 10.0.1.1* statically maps 192.168.88.1 to **foo**'s physical address.

Basically, it's a chicken-and-the-egg problem. Normally, you'd query the NHS for a tunnel endpoint's physical address, but you need to know the NHS's physical address in order to query it. Thus, the static mapping.